# Hooking a procedure last

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I'm currently making a plugin for one application and since it doesn't handle the WM_MBUTTONDOWN message I decided to hook the WNDPROC but it seems that another plugin hooks it too and handles this message (since the application loads the plugins in alphabetical order, there's a chance that I might not hook the WNDPROC last, resulting in the other plugin handling the message first). This means I'd have to be the last one to hook the WNDPROC to be able to get to those messages.

So, are there any reliable (not relying on alphabetical order, etc.) ways of hooking a procedure last?

EDIT: the hooking is done by changing the DWL_WNDPROC property of the window to the address hook procedure using the SetWindowLong function. The original DWL_WNDPROC is then called from the hook procedure using CallWindowProc. Sorry for not making this clear!

Thanks,
Tuntuni.

Comment: Not any way that I know of, and it certainly didn't seem set up that way from Raymond's one blog.

Comment: @chris Could you provide me with a link to that article (or did I misunderstand you?)?

Comment: Not sure if I'll be able to find it, but here's one on [how they work in Win16](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/08/09/693280.aspx).

Comment: Common name for this technique is **window subclassing**, not the hooking which is associated with `SetWindowsHookEx` function installing system-wide/thread-wide hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your installed window proc callback you could check current window proc by `GetWindowLongPtr` call and reinstall your proc with `SetWindowLongPtr` if someone changed it. Of course, it's dangerous and at least will require your window proc to be protected from reentrance (usually with static counter) to avoid infinite recursion.

Also you could try to use system-wide hook installed by [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function instead of window subclassing - [`WH_MOUSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`WH_MOUSE_LL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) hook instead of `WH_CALLWNDPROC`. It shall be called before window procedure is called (on `GetMessage` or even on mouse message posting for LL hook), therefore it shall occur before any `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook is called.

Comment: I'm not really sure this would work because the application calls GetMessage and CallWindowProc between each one of the plugins (when it loads them). Are there any other ways you could think of?

Comment: @Tuntuni Did not get your point. If other plugin use `WH_CALLWNDPROC` hook, your `WH_MOUSE` hook always will be called BEFORE it, disregarding actual hooks installation order. At least it shall according to documentation (didn't tried it really).

Comment: I forgot to explain how the hooking is done. I'm very sorry. I have edited the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will test out this method and see if it works. Also, thank you for telling me the correct term for "this kind of hooking".

Comment: Ahh! Now I understand what you were trying to say with the WH_MOUSE! I haven't tried it yet but it sounds like it is going to work! :) Thanks!